# How to extract certain substring from a multi line string in Python?

Tags: python, regex, string

I have a string which looks like below

```
answer = """
models sold in last 4 weeks
+---------------+
|      pcid     |
+---------------+
|     22bv03    |
|     3eer3d    |
|  fes44h2j555j |
| 4mee33ikj5sq1 |
|  99dkk3bvr32a |
| cv44trmq011sa |
|    lo33xc1a   |
+---------------+***For more information, please visit the company page.
"""
```

Now I need to extract just the `table` from the string such that the end result looks like

```
+---------------+
|      pcid     |
+---------------+
|     22bv03    |
|     3eer3d    |
|  fes44h2j555j |
| 4mee33ikj5sq1 |
|  99dkk3bvr32a |
| cv44trmq011sa |
|    lo33xc1a   |
+---------------+
```

Now I tried doing something like this

```
answer.split("***")[0].split("\n")[1]
```

But doing so, I only get the header against the expected `table`.

How do I ensure that I can only extract `table` from the string? Is there any `regex` that can be applied here?

Comment: Why regex? You may just find the first index of the `+---------------+` string, then get the substring till the last `+---------------+` string. See https://ideone.com/HNYsmN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might try:

```
answer = re.sub(r'^.*?(?=\+-)|\*\*\*.*$', '', answer, flags=re.DOTALL)
print(answer)
```

This prints:

```
+---------------+
|      pcid     |
+---------------+
|     22bv03    |
|     3eer3d    |
|  fes44h2j555j |
| 4mee33ikj5sq1 |
|  99dkk3bvr32a |
| cv44trmq011sa |
|    lo33xc1a   |
+---------------+
```

The regex uses an alternation, to handle trimming the answer string at both the beginning and the end.  First:

```
^.*?(?=\+-)
```

removes all content from the start of the string up to, but not including, the start of the table (`+-`).  The second part:

```
\*\*\*.*$
```

removes all content from the start of the footnote (`***`) until the end of the string.

Comment: I do not want the header. Just the table.

Comment: @SouvikRay I had a slight problem in there, and should have been using DOT ALL mode.

Answer (score 1):

It looks as though you wanted to match from the first occurrence of a fixed delimiter to the last occurrence of the same delimiter.

In this case, you do not have to use a regex:

```
sep = '+---------------+'
start = answer.find(sep)
end = answer.rfind(sep)
print(answer[start:end+len(sep)])
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/HNYsmN) yieling

```
+---------------+
|      pcid     |
+---------------+
|     22bv03    |
|     3eer3d    |
|  fes44h2j555j |
| 4mee33ikj5sq1 |
|  99dkk3bvr32a |
| cv44trmq011sa |
|    lo33xc1a   |
+---------------+
```

With regex, you may directly match from the first till last occurrence of the separator:

```
import re
answer = """
models sold in last 4 weeks
+---------------+
|      pcid     |
+---------------+
|     22bv03    |
|     3eer3d    |
|  fes44h2j555j |
| 4mee33ikj5sq1 |
|  99dkk3bvr32a |
| cv44trmq011sa |
|    lo33xc1a   |
+---------------+***For more information, please visit the company page.
"""
sep = '+---------------+'
m = re.search(r'(?sm)^{0}.*{0}'.format(re.escape(sep)), answer)
if m:
    print(m.group())
```

See [another regex demo](https://ideone.com/lPykRn)

**Regex details**

- `(?sm)` - dot now matches line breaks and `^` matches start of a line
- `^` - start of a line
- `\+---------------\+`  - a separator pattern
- `.*` - any 0+ chars as many as possible
- `\+---------------\+` - separator pattern

Comment: yes this is another solution without using regex. Thanks for the alternate approach.

Comment: @SouvikRay I actually added a direct dynamic *regex extraction* approach that will work for any kind of separators.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this as follows

Step 1: 
Identify the Index range by running below code

```
print(answer.index("ks")) 

print(answer.index("***"))
```

You will find out index range of table i.e `[28:226]` and comment out this code once you found the range.

Step 2:

```
print(answer[28:226])
```